# Ubuntu 12.04 ODBC connection to MySQL

Tags: 12.04, mysql, asterisk, odbc

I have task - write CEL events into mysql. I wrote next setting:

odbcinst.ini =>

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

Drivers located as well.
Next is  /etc/odbc.ini - connection to db.

```
[asterisk]                         # my system DSN
Description = description of your DSN
Driver      = MySQL                         # custom driver name
Server      = localhost                    
Port        = 3306                          # custom port 
Socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock   # socket
Database    = asteriskcdrdb                 # MySQL DB name 
UserName    = admin
Password    = 123456
Option      = 3
ReadOnly    = No
```

When i use "odbcinst -s -q", i get

```
root@astes:~# odbcinst -s -q
[asterisk]
```

Then i believe system see my dsn.
But when i use "isql asterisk -v", i get

```
root@astes:~# isql asterisk -v
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

What did i wrong? 
I installed mysql-connector and ODBC.

**UPD**: when i use "reload" in CLI* i get

```
[Feb  1 03:41:02] NOTICE[3135]: res_odbc.c:1481 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting asterisk
[Feb  1 03:41:02] WARNING[3135]: res_odbc.c:1508 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Error SQLConnect=-1 errno=0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[Feb  1 03:41:02] WARNING[3135]: res_odbc.c:1329 _ast_odbc_request_obj2: Failed to connect to asterisk
[Feb  1 03:41:02] WARNING[3135]: cel_odbc.c:125 load_config: No such connection 'asterisk' in the 'first' section of cel_odbc.conf.  Check res_odbc.conf.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change driver to newest, and it works.